# How to make Bootstrap nav bar the same width with div

Tags: html

The dark grey Bootstrap navigation bar renders few pixels narrower than Bootstrap two green-and-blue columns  which is placed below. How can I fix it so the navigation bar and the  are the same width?

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">my logo</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10" style="padding: 0px; background-color: lightgreen; height: 100vh">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="padding: 0; background-color: lightblue; height: 100vh">
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the code shown inside a div with class of "container" or "container-fluid"? You can try `.no-gutters` class on `<div class="row">` which would look like this: `<div class="row no-gutters">`. That gets rid of negative margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container are required when using the default grid system. The two most common containers are:

1. `.container`, which sets a max-width for the page content
2. `.container-fluid`, which will take the full width of the screen
3. `.container-{breakpoint}`, which behaves like `.container-fluid` until it reaches the breakpoint then behaves like a `.container`.

You will find more details in [the very clear documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/).
If we consider the second solution, putting your content in a `div.container-fluid` fixes the problem:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">my logo</a>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10" style="padding: 0px; background-color: lightgreen; height: 100vh">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="padding: 0; background-color: lightblue; height: 100vh">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify why container-fluid helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: @ alphanumeric Edited.